# iOS: Parsing a xml from HTTP using NSXMLParser for

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsxmlparser

It's first time using NSXMLParser and wondering if you give me some direction of parsing the returned xml from an http request that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<theresponse>
 <status>OK</status>
 <pricing currency="USD" symbol="$">
   <price class="items">24.00</price>
   <price class="shipping">6.00</price>
   <price class="tax">1.57</price>
 </pricing>
</theresponse>
```

I know the basic of parsing delegate methods, I just want to know what the code would look like in didEndElement/foundCharacters/didStartElement for retreiving above items(currency/items/shipping/tax)? any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little more tricky than some standard `NSXMLParser` code; Because essentially when you are looking for the "`shipping`" you want "`6.00`" but those two pieces of data are returned to you in different delegate methods, which is normal. But usually the element would be named "`shipping`" so in `parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:` you would automatically have the element name as it was passed into the method.

The solution would seem simple, have a `_currentAttributes` ivar and in `parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:` do something like `_currentAttributes = attributeDict;` and then handle this in the `didEndElement:` method. However this style would easily break, even on this moderately simple `XML`.

My way of handling this would be to store the attributes dictionary passed into the `didStartElement:` and set it in a dictionary as the object for the key of the element name. Combining this style with the standard use of an `NSMutableString` as a characterBuffer of sorts allows you to put all of your logic into the `didEndElement:` method.

Side note: I am also quite fond of having my `NSXMLParserDelegate` classes be `NSXMLParser` subclasses, as this one is. However the delegate methods would be identical if it were not.

**ItemParser.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface ItemParser : NSXMLParser <NSXMLParserDelegate>
@property (readonly) NSDictionary *itemData;
@end
```

**ItemParser.m**

```
#import "ItemParser.h"
@implementation ItemParser {
    NSMutableDictionary *_itemData;
    NSMutableDictionary *_attributesByElement;
    NSMutableString *_elementString;
}
-(NSDictionary *)itemData{
    return [_itemData copy];
}
-(void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    _itemData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    _attributesByElement = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    _elementString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    // Save the attributes for later.
    if (attributeDict) [_attributesByElement setObject:attributeDict forKey:elementName];
    // Make sure the elementString is blank and ready to find characters
    [_elementString setString:@""];
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    // Save foundCharacters for later
    [_elementString appendString:string];
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"status"]){
        // Element status only contains a string i.e. "OK"
        // Simply set a copy of the element value string in the itemData dictionary
        [_itemData setObject:[_elementString copy] forKey:elementName];
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"pricing"]) {
        // Pricing has an interesting attributes dictionary 
        // So copy the entries to the item data
        NSDictionary *attributes = [_attributesByElement objectForKey:@"pricing"];
        [_itemData addEntriesFromDictionary:attributes];
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"price"]) {
        // The element price occurs multiple times.
        // The meaningful designation occurs in the "class" attribute.
        NSString *class = [[_attributesByElement objectForKey:elementName] objectForKey:@"class"];
        if (class) [_itemData setObject:[_elementString copy] forKey:class];
    }
    [_attributesByElement removeObjectForKey:elementName];
    [_elementString setString:@""];
}
-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    _attributesByElement = nil;
    _elementString = nil;
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError{
    NSLog(@"%@ with error %@",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),parseError.localizedDescription);
}
-(BOOL)parse{
    self.delegate = self;
    return [super parse];
}
@end
```

And so to test I stored the `XML` you posted above into a file named "ItemXML.xml". And tested it using this code:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"ItemXML" withExtension:@"xml"];
ItemParser *parser = [[ItemParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
[parser parse];
NSLog(@"%@",parser.itemData);
```

The result I got was:

```
{
    currency = USD;
    items = "24.00";
    shipping = "6.00";
    status = OK;
    symbol = "$";
    tax = "1.57";
}
```